# Where to fill JPA database with initially available values?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee

I have a Java EE 7 project with a web frontend and I'd like to present some lazily-initialized initial choice to the user which he_she can then complement. The `@PostConstruct` method of the EJB seemed like a good place, but [it doesn't guarantee that a transaction is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147788/why-am-i-getting-a-transactionrequiredexception-in-postconstruct-method-in-jta/43148193#43148193).

I'm looking for the most elegant solution, eventually a place which has been foreseen for this task.

The `@PostConstruct` method of an `@ApplicationScoped` managed bean in the web frontend would be an option, but I'd still have to make a bogus call to get it initialized - it's way, but maybe not the most elegant one.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the `javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source` property in your persistence.xml file.

It points at a SQL script that will preload your database. This can be a resource embedded in your application or an external file URL.

Comment: But that script would need extra maintenance if a change to the entity model occurs, right? And I'd have to figure out how the JPA provider stores the data in different databases. A programmatic solution is the only option imo.